# Contravariant Interfaces referring to their own types

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the following pathfinding code:

```
public interface INode
{
    List<INode> GetNeighbours();
    float GetMovementCost(INode other);
}

public static class Pathfinder
{
    public static List<INode> FindPath(INode origin, INode target) 
    {
        var path = new List<INode>();
        var cameFrom = new Dictionary<INode, INode>();
        var costToNode = new Dictionary<INode, float>();
        var frontier = new PriorityQueue<INode>();
        Dictionary<INode, float> costSoFar = new Dictionary<INode, float>();

        frontier.Enqueue(origin, 0);
        costSoFar[frontier[0].Element] = 0;


        while (frontier.Count > 0)
        {
            INode current = frontier.Dequeue();
            foreach (var neighbour in current.GetNeighbours())
            {
                float newCost = costSoFar[current] +
                                current.GetMovementCost(neighbour);
                if (!costSoFar.ContainsKey(neighbour) || newCost < costSoFar[neighbour])
                {
                    costSoFar[neighbour] = newCost;
                    frontier.Enqueue(neighbour, newCost);
                    cameFrom[neighbour] = current;
                }
            }
            if (current == target)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        //build path
        INode nn = target;
        while (nn != origin)
        {
            path.Add(nn);
            nn = cameFrom[nn];
        }
        path.Reverse();
        return path;

    }

    public struct PriorityElement<T>
    {
        public T Element;
        public float Priority;

        public PriorityElement(T element, float priority)
        {
            if (priority < 0) throw new Exception("Priorities must be non-negative");
            Element = element;
            Priority = priority;
        }
    }

    public class PriorityQueue<T> : List<PriorityElement<T>>
    {
        public void Enqueue(T element, float priority)
        {
            if (this.Count == 0)
            {
                this.Insert(0, new PriorityElement<T>(element, priority));
                return;
            }
            if (priority > this.Last().Priority)
            {
                this.Add(new PriorityElement<T>(element, priority));
                return;
            }
            var firstLowerThan = this.First(p => priority <= p.Priority);
            this.Insert(IndexOf(firstLowerThan), new PriorityElement<T>(element, priority));
        }

        public T Dequeue()
        {
            if (this.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot dequeue, queue is empty");
            }
            var ret = this.First();
            this.Remove(ret);
            return ret.Element;
        }
    }       
}
```

This works fine, but the really annoying thing is it returns a INode and not something that impliments INode, so I have to cast it back up and its not very type safe.

I am trying to implement the generic version of this code, something along the lines of:

```
public static List<Node> FindPath<Node>(Node origin, Node target) where Node : INode<Node>
```

However this obviously doesn't work as `List<INode> GetNeighbours();` cannot return a more derived type without using covariance and contravariance. Implementing contravariance is tricky here.

Can someone please help me redefine my INode interface such that the above signature will work? The main issue is that `GetNeighbours()` needs to return a list of a move derived type of INode.

Something along the lines of:

```
public interface INode
{
    List<T> GetNeighbours<T>() where T : INode; 
    float GetMovementCost(INode other);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FindPath` should take arguments of type `T` where `T : class, INode`, rather than explicitly taking `INode` arguments. Then, inside the method, you should refer to `T` rather than `INode`. For example, you could write:

```
public static List<T> FindPath<T>(T origin, T target) where T : class, INode
{
    var path = new List<T>();
    var cameFrom = new Dictionary<T, T>();
    var costToNode = new Dictionary<T, float>();
    var frontier = new PriorityQueue<T>();
    Dictionary<T, float> costSoFar = new Dictionary<T, float>();

    frontier.Enqueue(origin, 0);
    costSoFar[frontier[0].Element] = 0;


    while (frontier.Count > 0)
    {
        T current = frontier.Dequeue();
        foreach (var neighbour in current.GetNeighbours<T>())
        {
            float newCost = costSoFar[current] +
                            current.GetMovementCost(neighbour);
            if (!costSoFar.ContainsKey(neighbour) || newCost < costSoFar[neighbour])
            {
                costSoFar[neighbour] = newCost;
                frontier.Enqueue(neighbour, newCost);
                cameFrom[neighbour] = current;
            }
        }
        if (current == target)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //build path
    T nn = target;
    while (nn != origin)
    {
        path.Add(nn);
        nn = cameFrom[nn];
    }
    path.Reverse();
    return path;
}
```

And then simply change your interface to:

```
public interface INode
{
    List<T> GetNeighbours<T>() where T : INode;
    float GetMovementCost(INode other);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was very close. I had just forgotten to add the type to GetNeighbours<T> in my pathfinding code. Is the reason why this works because List<T> implements IEnumerable<T> which is contravariant or am I reading too much into this?

Comment: @pseudoabdul There's no co/contra-variance here - its works because we're explicitly creating a `List<T>` and returning a `List<T>`. Previously, you were creating a `List<Node>` and trying to return a `List<T>`